# How do I know when a copy job is done?

Tags: c#, asp.net, callback, copy

I'm using

```
File.Copy(source, dest);
```

I need to know when this copy job is done processing so that it can move on to another task.

Is there any callback function I could use in this particular case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I delay a vb.net program until a file operation completes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437396/how-do-i-delay-a-vb-net-program-until-a-file-operation-completes)

Comment: I've given you some code to help you out...

Answer (score 6):

`File.Copy` is not asynchronous.  It has completed when the call finishes.

Answer (score 2):

[File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx) is blocking so execution should wait until the operation has complete.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't File.Copy a blocking method?  It should wait on that line until the copy of the file is complete then continue execution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to do what you need...cause I'm awesome that way :-)

```
dim FileCopyDelegate as new Delegate = addressof File.Copy

dim oListOfParams as new List(of string)

oListOfParams.add(source)
oListOfParams.add(destination)

FileCopyDelegate.begininvoke(oListOfParams, addressof CallBackMethod) 'creates an async thread to do the file copy
```